# Delete duplicated rows with same values but in different column in R

Tags: r

I want to remove the rows that are duplicated, for example if A==B and B==A, I want to keep just one of it. I have a dataframe looks like this:

```
|A      |B      |
|-------|-------|
|A1CF   |APOBEC1|
|A1CF   |KHSRP  |
|A1CF   |SYNCRIP|
|APOBEC1|A1CF   |
|SYNCRIP|A1CF   |
```

and my expected output is like this:

```
|A      |B      |
|-------|-------|
|A1CF   |APOBEC1|
|A1CF   |KHSRP  |
|A1CF   |SYNCRIP|
```

I have tried these,but it doesn't work.

```
df[!duplicated(df[,c("A","B")]),]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a least/greatest trick, and then remove duplicates:

```r
library(SparkR)

df <- unique(cbind(least(df$A, df$B), greatest(df$A, df$B)))
```

Here is a base R version of the above:

```r
df <- unique(cbind(ifelse(df$A < df$B, df$A, df$B),
                   ifelse(df$A >= df$B, df$A, df$B)))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I tried this but SparkR is not available for Rstudio 4.0.5.

Comment: @JennyEmpawi I updated with a base R version which should run everywhere.  Slightly more verbose though.